# Extract Text from within a string Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, extract, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a string of text that needs to be separated and placed in different cells.

[image: https://imgur.com/NWlm9UD]

This is for Google Sheets. The text string will be input via a barcode scanner. I have searched `=regextract` with no luck.

```
Raw Input           (1) (2) (3)
(1)123(2)456(3)789  123 456 789
(1)ABC(2)DEF(3)GHI  ABC DEF GHI
(1)JKL(2)MNO(3)PQR
```

I would like the raw input to take the contents after the guiding parenthesis and place that content in different cells

Comment: (1) : `=mid($A4,4,3)`, (2): `=mid($A4,10,3)`, (3): `=mid($A4,16,3)`

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. This does work for this example but unfortunately there may be different sized strings that are not only 3 characters so I believe this would not work universally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it all in one go with:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\((\d+)\)", "♦"), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

**Predictable length intervals**
(1) `=mid($A4,4,3)`
(2) `=mid($A4,10,3)`
(3) `=mid($A4,16,3)`

**Un-Predictable length intervals**
(1) `=mid(A7,(search($B$6,$A7))+(len(B$6)),(search($C$6,$A7))-(search($B$6,$A7))-(len(B$6)))`

(2) `=mid(A7,(search($C$6,$A7))+(len(C$6)),(search($D$6,$A7))-(search($C$6,$A7))-(len(C$6)))`

(3) `=mid(A7,(search($D$6,$A7))+3,(len($A7))-(search($D$6,$A7)))`

---

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Excellent Response! Do you think it would be possible to come up with a solution that would work if the (01) (02) and (03) were out of order or if one were missing? Thanks for taking the time to show me how to do this with unpredictable length intervals!

Comment: "if the (01) (02) and (03) were out of order or if one were missing?" Possibly/probably, but you should post this as a new question. Why? Because you need to describe your goal, explain how/whether this event might occur, provide an example of a successful outcome, etc. BTW (for the future), please don't supply just screenshots of your spreadsheet, please share a copy of your spreadsheet (less private or confidential information) and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Will do thank you for your guidance in better explaining the full event. I will attempt to be more complete when I repost this question! Thank you!